# use popToRootViewController and pass Data

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pass-data, poptoviewcontroller

I'm applying for a junior developer position and I've got a very specific task, that already took me 3 days to complete. Sounds easy - pass data to rootViewController.
That's what I've done:

1)

```
   private func userDefaultsToRootController() {
        let input = textField.text!
        defaults.set(input, forKey: "SavedLabel")
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

2. private func segueToRootViewController() {
   let destinationVC = MainScreen1()
   let input = textField.text!

   ```
     if input == "" { self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) }

     destinationVC.input = input
     navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
   ```

   }
3. 

```
private func popToNavigationController() {
    let input = textField.text!
    if let rootVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? MainScreen1 {
        rootVC.input = input
    }
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

4. I've used CoreData

But here is the difficult part - I've got an email, that all these methods are not good enough and I need to use delegate and closure. I've done delegation and closures before, but when I popToRootViewController delegate method passes nil. Could you at least point where to find info about this?

** ADDED **

There are 2 View Controllers: Initial and Second one.
That's what I have in the Initial View Controller:

```
var secondVC = MainScreen2()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
        secondVC.delegate = self
    }
```

That's how I push SecondViewController

```
@objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        
        let nextViewController = MainScreen2()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
                
    }
```

In SecondViewController I've got this protocol

```
protocol PassData {
    func transferData(text: String)
}
```

Also a delegate:

```
var delegate: PassData?
```

This is how I go back to initial view controller

```
@objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        
        if let input = textField.text {
            print(input)
            self.delegate?.transferData(text: input)
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
        
    }
```

Back to the Initial view controller where I've implemented delegate method

```
extension MainScreen1: PassData {
    func transferData(text: String) {
        print("delegate called")
        label.text = text
        
    }
}
```

Delegate doesn't get called.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint to check if your delegate method is being called in your  initial view controller? Did you set the delegate as self in your initial view controller?

Comment: I set delegate to self in the initial view controller, but it doesn't get called

Comment: it is wrong the place where you set the delegate. You be must set it in your `buttonTapped` function, not in `viewDidLoad`. That's not the instance you are pushing in the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASED ON YOUR EDIT:

You must set the delegate in `buttonTapped`

```
@objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    
    let nextViewController = MainScreen2()
    nextViewController.delegate = self // HERE WHERE YOU SET THE DELEGATE
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
            
}
```

You can delete the second instance and your code in `viewDidLoad`. That's not the instance you push.

This should point you in the right direction to use delegation and completion handler.

```
protocol YourDelegateName {
   func passData(data:YourDataType)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  var delegate: YourDelegateName?

  func passDataFromSecondViewController(){

     YourCoreDataClass.shared.getCoreData { (yourStringsArray) in
     self.delegate?.passData(data: yourStringsArray)
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
     }
  }

class InitialViewController: UIViewController, YourDelegateName {


   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // or whenever you instantiate your SecondViewController
      let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
      secondViewController.delegate = self //VERY IMPORTANT, MANY MISS THIS 
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(createVC, animated: true)
    }


   func passData(data:YourDataType){
       //user your data
   }

}


class YourCoreDataClass: NSObject {
    
     static let  shared = YourCoreDataClass()

     func getCoreData (completion: ([String]) -> ()){
        ........... your code 
         let yourStringsArray = [String]() // let's use as example an array of strings
         //when you got the data your want to pass
         completion(yourStringsArray)
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, somewhy the delegate doesn't get called. My implementation is exactly like yours.

Comment: are you sure you are using the same instance that gets pushed by the Navigation Controller? Can you post your code?

Comment: There are only 2 ViewControllers. Initial and Second one. While I'm on the Second View Controller I use the method ` navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) ` . I believe it is the same instance.

Comment: I mean when you push your second view controller? Can you show the part where you set the delegate to self and push it in the Initial?

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Comment: I am glad it worked. Can you please accept the answer. ;)